# Javascript Multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push the values [100,1000,10000,200,2000,20000,300,3000,30000]
inside the multidimensional array in Javascript.

Multidimensional array should look like below

[[100,1000,10000],[200,2000,20000],[300,3000,30000]]

I am using the below code

```
var j = 0;
var x = 0;
var z = 0;
var f = new Array();

var rows = [100, 1000, 10000, 200, 2000, 20000, 300, 3000, 30000];
for (var i = 1; i <= rows.length; i++) {
    if (j < i) {
        f[x] = new Array();

        var arrval = parseInt(rows[j]);
        f[x][z] = arrval;
        z++;

        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            x++;
            z = 0;
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

But the push into multidimensional array push seems to be not working.
The final output is looking like [[,,10000],[,,20000],[,,30000]]

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing f[x] each iteration!

Here is a fix :)

```
var rows = [100,1000,10000,200,2000,20000,300,3000,30000];

var x=0; var z=0; var f = new Array();
for (var i=1;i<=rows.length;i++) {
    if(!f[x]){
        f[x]=new Array();
    };

    f[x][z]=parseInt(rows[i-1]);

    z++;
    if(i%3==0)
    {
        x++;
        z = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 var rows = [100, 1000, 10000, 200, 2000, 20000, 300, 3000, 30000];
    var newarr = new Array();
    /*for(var i =0; i< rows.length; i++){
        newarr.push(rows.splice(0,3));
    }
    console.log(newarr);*/

    while(rows.length){
       newarr.push(rows.splice(0,3)); 
    }
```

You can even make a function that would receive the number of columns as parameters.

```
function(orArr, nArr, cols){
    for(var i =0; i< orArr.length; i++){
    nArr.push(rows.splice(0,cols));
}
```

#### Update

: You should actually use slice() instead of splice() . as your original array would be modified if you are using splice();
In that case your code would be:

```
var newarr = new Array();
for(var i =0; i< rows.length; i++){
        newarr.push(rows.slice(0,3));
}
console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it with a single loop
http://jsfiddle.net/rene3/

```
var f = [];

var rows = [100, 1000, 10000, 200, 2000, 20000, 300, 3000, 30000];

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len ; i++) {
    if( !(i%3) ){
       f.push([]);
    }
    f[Math.floor(i/3)].push(rows[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = [];

f.push([[100,1000,10000],[200,2000,20000],[300,3000,30000]]);
```

if there should be a dynamic loop, you could try:

```
var f = [];
var MyVal = n; // n = any value you like
var Val100, Val1000, Val10000;

for (var i=1; i<MyVal+1; i++){

Val100 = i*100;
Val1000 = i*1000;
Val10000 = i*10000;

f.push([Val100,Val1000,Val10000]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = new Array(),
    x = 0,
    rows = [100, 1000, 10000, 200, 2000, 20000, 300, 3000, 30000];

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var a;
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        f[x] = new Array();
        a = f[x];
        x++;
    }
    a.push(rows[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3R35Q/